# `print` function doesn't work in Python when mixed with `os.system` statements

Tags: python-3.x, printf, stdout

I have a program performing extensive numerical computation; the main loop has the following shape:

```
for d in data:
    # compute stuff
    print(current_pattern)
    os.system( external_program_printing_on_stdout + str(current_pattern))
```

I think the name of the variables above tells enough about their content.

I run the program with `pypy3 script.py | tee log.txt` but _I only get the `stdout` of the `os.system` call, the previous `print` being lost. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just found it!

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

(after the `print` function).